# Custom YouTube Plugin loading different PHP library on live site and localhost

Tags: php, youtube

It's come to my attention that the original question was a little unclear.

I'm working on a custom-built YouTube plugin for WordPress which has passed all the tests on my local installation, but as soon as I try to run it on a live site, I start seeing fatal errors on the settings page:

[image]

The error occurs during a utility function I have to check whether or not the OAuth authentication is valid.

As shown in the screenshot, I fail when trying to call the `Google_Client::getConfig()` function, which is allegedly undefined.

This is unusual, because if this function was truly undefined, my test site would see the same errors, and (as pictured below), the function clearly exists:
[image]

I did a `var_dump()` of `get_class_methods()` in both locations. On my test site, that produced 60 methods, one of which was the expected `getConfig()`. On the live site, however, I only had 48 methods, and `getConfig()` was not one of them.

It seems likely that there is some sort of versioning issue with the way I've included the Google API, but I haven't been able to zero in on it.

The live site site is clearly loading a different version of the `Google_Client` class, but I don't know where that could be coming from because the version I've included in the plugin definitely has the methods in question.

Comment: You might be informed that, third party plugin specific questions are off-topic here. I'm sure you've already read the [faq]. You should ask the question to the plugin support forum.

Comment: My mistake. I assumed referring to it as a custom plugin was enough to indicate that this is a plugin I am writing myself. It seem likely that there is an issue with the way I've loaded Google's PHP library within that plugin. As that's the only reason I can think of as to why it's not loading the class version in the included file. I'm looking for insight into general, plugin related core functions that might cause and/or influence this discrepancy.

Comment: Can you please show how you included the files? Did you use a package manager like Composer? Are those sub-repos in Git, Mercurial, …?

Answer (score 0):

After exhausting all other options, I uploaded the plugin to another site I manage, and it worked perfectly. Once I narrowed it down to an issue with a specific domain, I was able to identify the problem in the active theme.

The original theme I built for the site in question had some YouTube functionality baked in (major no-no), and that's proved to be the source of the conflict. Conveniently, that theme is being phased out, so this issue will resolve itself once the transition is complete.